# How to detect an inline js function using jsoup?I basically wanted to check if the inline function is present or not.

Tags: javascript, inline, jsoup

How to detect an inline js function using jsoup? I basically wanted to check if the inline function is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not possible to execute javascript code with the jsoup. That's why you are not able to check whether the particular function exists. You can just parse DOM with this tool.

You should use something like HTMLUnit( http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ ) to be able to call JS functions or statements.